Why a function induced by the infimum of the arclength of curves is Lipschitz?
Recently I have read a paper "Weighted Trudinger-type Inequalities" written by Stephen M. Buckley and Julann O'Shea and published by Indiana University Mathematics Journal in 1999, MR1722194, Zbl 0965.46024. I have some questions of pp. 95-96 of this paper.
Now let me state the background of this paper. Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n\ (n\geqslant 2)$ be a domain (i.e., open connected set). Given a point $x_0\in \Omega$. Let $\{S_i\}_{i=0}^j,\ j\geqslant 2$ be a pairwise disjoint collection of open subsets of $\Omega$ with $x_0\in S_0$.
Define
$$
  l_i(y)=\inf_{\lambda\in \mathcal{F}_{y,x_0}}\mathrm{len} (\lambda\cap S_i),\quad y\in \Omega,\quad 0<i<j,
$$
where $\mathcal{F}_{y,x_0}$ is the set of all rectifiable curves in $\Omega$ joining $y$ and $x_0$, and $\mathrm{len}(\lambda\cap S_i)$ stands for the arc length of $\lambda$ lying in $S_i$. Then $l_i$ is Lipschitz and
$$
\tag{$*$}\label{*}
  |\nabla l_i|\leqslant 1.
$$
My questions are:

Why $l_i$ is Lipschitz?

Why \eqref{*} holds?

Why $\nabla l_i$ is supported on $S_i$?


For those questions, I am sure that $l_i$ is locally Lipschitz with constant $1$ on $\Omega$, that is, any point in $\Omega$ has a neighborhood on which $l_i$ is Lipschitz with constant $1$. Hence by Rademacher's theorem, we know that $l_i$ is differentiable a.e. in $\Omega$. But question 1 and 2 seem require $l_i$ is (global) Lipschitz with constant $1$ on $\Omega$, that is, for any $x',x''\in \Omega$,
\begin{equation}\tag{${**}$}\label{**}
  |l_i(x')-l_i(x'')|\leqslant |x'-x''|.
\end{equation}
I do not know how to prove \eqref{**}.
********************************************
Update:
$x_0$ and $\{S_i\}$ come from the following property: Suppose $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n\ (n\geqslant 2)$ is a domain with a distinguished point $x_0$ and $C_0>1$. We say $\Omega$ has the $C_0$-slice property with respect to $x_0$ if, for each $x\in \Omega$, there is a path $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to \Omega$, $\gamma(0)=x_0$, $\gamma(1)=x$, and a pairwise disjoint collection of open subsets $\{S_i\}_{i=0}^j, j\geqslant 2$ of $\Omega$ such that

$x_0\in S_0$, $x\in S_j$, and $x_0$ and $x$ are in different connected components of $\Omega\setminus \overline{S}_i$ for all $0<i<j$.

If $\lambda$ is a curve containing both $x$ and $x_0$, and $0<i<j$, then
\begin{equation*}
  \mathrm{diam}(S_i)\leqslant C_0\mathrm{len}(\lambda\cap S_i).
\end{equation*}

$  \gamma\bigl([0,1])\subset \bigcup_{i=0}^j \overline{S}_i.$

There exists $x_i\in \gamma_i\equiv \gamma([0,1])\cap S_i$, such that $x_0$ is as previously defined, $x_j=x$, and $B(x_j,2r_i)\subset S_i$, where $r_i=C_0^{-1}\mathrm{diam}(S_i)$. Additionally, $\delta(x)\geqslant C_0^{-1}\mathrm{diam}(S_i)$, for all $x\in \gamma_i,\ 0\leqslant i\leqslant j$.



Sorry, what is meant by $x_0$ lies in different connected components of $\Omega \setminus \bar S_i$?

Concerning your question 2, a point at which $|\nabla l_i| > 1$ would not be a point of local Lipschitz constant $1$ of $l_i$.

Sorry, I extracted one sentence from the paper, and it seemed confusing. Therefore, I deleted this sentence and added a full description at the end. @NateRiver

Your observation "I am sure that $l_i$ is locally Lipschitz ..." is correct. For general $\Omega$ an assertion about being globally Lipschitz is false. Neither is it needed here. As Nate River already noted, assertion $(*)$ is a trivial consequence of being locally $1,$−Lipschitz. Point 3. is false. There should be the closure of $S_i,$, noting that $l_i$ is locally constant outside ${\rm Cl,}S_i$ almost directly by its definition.

Thank you, @TaQ! I understand $()$, since differentiability is a local property; hence, locally Lipschitz is enough for us to  desire $()$. But I am not sure about your comment on 3. Could you please write the precise process of it? Thank you!

If $y_1$ and $y_2$ can be joined inside $\Omega$ by line segment not meeting $S_i,$, then for every (rectifiable) curve going inside $\Omega$ from $x_0$ to $y_1$ there is the curve $x_0\to y_1\to y_2$ with the same length of the part that is inside $S_i,$, and conversely. So the sets whose infimums are $l_i(y_1)$ and $l_i(y_2)$ are the same, and so $l_i(y_2)=l_i(y_2)$ holds. Every point in $\Omega\setminus{\rm Cl,}S_i$ has an open neighbourhood $N$ such that the above holds for all $y_1,y_2\in N,$. Does this make sense to you?

Thank you, @TaQ!
